# How keep the selected value for dropdown after submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do I keep the selected item after page refreshed ,i have a language in the multiple select,

i am try now this with java script here is my code its not working ,can any one guide me how to make it selected

my html code

```
<div class="control-group">
<label for="textfield" class="control-label">Language</label>
<div  class="controls">
    <select name="myLanguage" id="myLanguage" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="English,">English,</option>
        <option value="Arabic,">Arabic,</option>
        <option value="Hindi,">Hindi,</option>
        <option value="Malayalam,">Malayalam,</option>
        <option value="Danish,">Danish,</option>

    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
 document.getElementById('myLanguage').value = "<?php echo $_GET['language'];?>";
```

Comment: do you really want a `multiple` select? in that case you have to set the name as an array and only use the multiple attr. `<select name='myLanguage[]' id='myLanguage' multiple>`. And if it is really multiple you need another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myLanguage').val("<?php echo $_GET['language'];?>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't use a session variables, so adding the value to the session isnt possible. Still you can do two things:

Option 1:
Add the value to a cookie with Jquery:

```
Set: $.cookie("test", 1);

Read: var value = $.cookie("test");
```

*See more: [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)*

Option 2:
Post the value to the new page and request on that one:

Reading the value can be done with :

```
Read: $_REQUEST["my_variable"];
```

Note: reading value can be done like:

```
$("#myLanguage option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5 as your `doctype` you can easily store values in the `localStorage`.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

To set it:

```
localStorage.setItem("variable_name", variable_value);
```

To get it:

```
localStorage.variable_name
```

To remove it:

```
localStorage.removeItem("variable_name");
```

You can also use js cookies with **jquery.cookie** plugin, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
As mentioned in the comments, when using the multiple attribute, 
the name attribute must be an array such as:

<div class="control-group">
    <label for="myLanguage[]" class="control-label">Language</label>
    <div  class="controls">
        <select name="myLanguage[]"  multiple="multiple"> 
            <option value="English,">English,</option>
            <option value="Arabic,">Arabic,</option>
            <option value="Hindi,">Hindi,</option>
            <option value="Malayalam,">Malayalam,</option>
            <option value="Danish,">Danish,</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

javascript // Note: I'm not so sure on the following syntax

   var myLanguage[] = document.elements('myLanguage[]').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$languages = array(
  'en' => 'english',
  'vi' => 'vietnamese',
  'cn' => 'chinese'
);

if (isset($_GET['lang']) AND array_key_exists($_GET['lang'], $languages))
{
    include './lang/' . $languages[$_GET['lang']] . '.php';
}
else
{
    include './lang/english.php';

}
?>
```